# How to use NtCreateSection in Go?

Tags: windows, go, winapi

I'm trying to learn how to use some Windows API calls in Go, specifically some of the lower level, undocumented functions. I'm following a C++ example [here](https://www.ired.team/offensive-security/code-injection-process-injection/ntcreatesection-+-ntmapviewofsection-code-injection) and trying to follow along with Go. Below is the output and a stripped-down example of what I'm trying to do:

> c0000005: The operation completed successfully.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "golang.org/x/sys/windows"
)

// Why are these not defined in the windows pkg?!
const SEC_COMMIT = 0x08000000
const SECTION_WRITE = 0x2
const SECTION_READ = 0x4
const SECTION_EXECUTE = 0x8
const SECTION_RWX = SECTION_WRITE | SECTION_READ | SECTION_EXECUTE

func createSection() error {
    var e error
    var err uintptr
    var ntdll *windows.LazyDLL
    var section uintptr

    // Load DLL
    ntdll = windows.NewLazySystemDLL("ntdll")

    // FIXME Allocate section
    err, _, e = ntdll.NewProc("NtCreateSection").Call(
        section,
        SECTION_RWX,
        0,
        uintptr(512),
        windows.PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE,
        SEC_COMMIT,
        0,
    )
    if err != 0 {
        return fmt.Errorf("%0x: %s", uint32(err), e.Error())
    } else if section == 0 {
        return fmt.Errorf("NtCreateSection failed for unknown reason")
    }
    fmt.Printf("%0x\n", section)

    return nil
}

func main() {
    var e error

    if e = createSection(); e != nil {
        fmt.Println(e.Error())
    }
}
```

From what I can tell, `c0000005` is an `Access Violation` error. The same code in C++ seems to work (see line 25 in the linked blog), however, the data types are slightly different. It's possible I'm using `var section uintptr` inappropriately. C++ uses a reference to a `HANDLE` which I think is also referred to as a `PHANDLE`. Go seems to use `uintptr` instead. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: *c0000005 is an Access Denied error.* - no, this is access violation - *The instruction at 0x%p referenced memory at 0x%p. The memory could not be %s.*

Comment: and in title *NtCreateThread* but in code *NtCreateSection*

Comment: *var section uintptr* - pointer to what ? faster of all here and error

Comment: *"specifically some of the lower level, undocumented functions"* - This isn't the Windows API. It's part of the Native API, not intended for general application use.

Comment: I don’t think you’re trying to do the correct thing. You don’t need any undocumented APIs for that. Call VirtualAllocEx to allocate memory in the target process. Call WriteProcessMemory to write any data or code there. Call CreateRemoteThread to launch a thread in that process.

Comment: If you know what you’re doing and you wrote position-independent code into that remote memory, you can launch a remote thread running the code you just wrote into that process. However, much easier way is only writing a path to your DLL, then call CreateRemoteThread passing the address or LoadLibrary function. This will load your DLL into the target process, which means the OS will follow the normal workflow, apply relocation table, etc.

Comment: If you want your thread running there, call CreateThread from the DllMain(process attach) of your DLL, this time no need for remote thread shenanigans, the DllMain already runs in the target process.

Comment: @RbMm good catch with the title, thanks! And `section` is a pointer/handle that gets set by the call to `NtCreateSection`. In C++ it is a `HANDLE` and then passed by reference. My understanding of the `windows` pkg in Go is that `uintptr` is used instead.

Comment: @Soonts Sorry, I definitely want to use the lower level calls. The blog I linked to is a Red Team blog. I'm trying to port some C++ code to Go that evades detection by EDRs.

Comment: section is pointer to what ? i not understand go and bad understand what you wrote

Comment: The sectionSize in the code on that website is 4096. I wonder if it needs to be the size of a page?

Comment: @RbMm `section` is a pointer to a section object. The little bit of [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntcreatesection) that I could find might explain it better than I could. Since the error states that it completed successfully, I was thinking that the Access Violation might be that the pointer I'm passing can't be set by the API call. Maybe I'm passing the wrong data type? The `windows` pkg has a `Handle` type, but it's just a `uintptr`. I can't find much on Google so I came here.

Comment: @LLawliet I have also tried 4096 without success. I had the same thought. In C++ I've changed the value to be smaller as well as the exact size of the buffer I planned to put in the section. All seemed to work in C++.

Comment: It's unreasonable to expect that 512 were a valid address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that the [function takes pointer arguments](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/index.html?page=UserMode%2FUndocumented%20Functions%2FNT%20Objects%2FSection%2FNtCreateSection.html) for the section handle and size.

This seemed to work:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"

    "golang.org/x/sys/windows"
)

// Why are these not defined in the windows pkg?!
const SEC_COMMIT = 0x8000000
const SECTION_WRITE = 0x2
const SECTION_READ = 0x4
const SECTION_EXECUTE = 0x8
const SECTION_RWX = SECTION_WRITE | SECTION_READ | SECTION_EXECUTE

func createSection() error {
    var e error
    var err uintptr
    var ntdll *windows.LazyDLL
    var section uintptr

    // Load DLL
    ntdll = windows.NewLazySystemDLL("ntdll")
    size := int64(4096)
    // FIXME Allocate section
    err, _, e = ntdll.NewProc("NtCreateSection").Call(
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&section)),
        SECTION_RWX,
        0,
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&size)),
        windows.PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE,
        SEC_COMMIT,
        0,
    )
    if err != 0 {
        return fmt.Errorf("%0x: %s", uint32(err), e.Error())
    } else if section == 0 {
        return fmt.Errorf("NtCreateSection failed for unknown reason")
    }
    fmt.Printf("%0x\n", section)

    return nil
}

func main() {
    var e error

    if e = createSection(); e != nil {
        fmt.Println(e.Error())
    }
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers aren't very helpful. At a minimum an answer needs to explain what the issue is and how the proposed solution addresses it. That said, the `size` variable you've introduced needs to be layout-compatible with a `LARGE_INTEGER`, yet I don't see that being enforced. Apart from that, its value need not be the page size. Passing 512 is perfectly ok. The system will perform rounding to a multiple of the page size as needed. It just needs a place to write that information.

Comment: True, I was working with a 64 bit system. Edited answer.

Comment: This answer is still devoid of any helpful information. The two points I listed in my previous comment are the *bare minimum* requirements for a quality answer.

Comment: Updated. Sorry about that.

Comment: Woah! I had tried the `uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&section)),` line, HOWEVER, I hadn't tried changing the size to be a pointer. I had copied the `uintptr(512)` from a `VirtualAlloc` call in other code I have. Looking at the documentation for `VirtualAlloc`, it looks to take a `SIZE_T` while `NtCreateSection` takes a `PLARGE_INTEGER`. All that to say that I was correct when I said I was using the wrong data type, but I had the wrong parameter. I can't believe I missed that (repeatedly). **THANKS!**